# How to make a method in class?

Tags: angular, typescript

My class currently looks like this:

```
export class Patient {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public location: string, public bedId: number, public severity: string,
                public trajectory: number, public vitalSigns: [GraphData[]], public latestReading: GraphData[]) {
    }

    public get combinedVSData(): Array<GraphData> {
        let combinedVitalSigns: GraphData[] = [];
        for (let data of this.vitalSigns) {
            combinedVitalSigns.push(data[0]);
        }
        return combinedVitalSigns;
    }
}
```

When I try to call `patient.combinedVSData`, it says it returns `undefined`. I've tried to simply make it return a string with the same result, and I've made console.log()'s in the method but i don't see anything in the console, so it doesn't get called at all. What am I doing wrong?

I'm calling the method in one of my templates like so:

```
 [results]="patientService.patientLevel3.combinedVSData"
```

I'm also calling it in one of my components' class just to test it:

```
onDrop(event: any){
let movedPatient: Patient = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData("patient"));
let from = parseInt(event.dataTransfer.getData("from"));

console.log(movedPatient.combinedVSData);

this.patientService.patientLevel3 = movedPatient;
this.patientService.removePatient(from, movedPatient.id);
}

}
```

Both cases it's undefined.

EDIT: I've found out that the reason combinedVSData is not on the object is because it apparently loses it when it gets converted to JSON. I don't know what can be done about it though.

Comment: how are you calling the getter method?

Comment: Make sure the TypeScript compiler targets ECMAScript5

Comment: @toskv I have update my question

Comment: @CozyAzure How to do that?

Comment: just use `getCombinedVSData()` in the template instead of property name.. check out the outputed js it should be obvious why.

Comment: @Jesper use the command `tsc --target ES5`. If you have your own build pipeline, make sure the underlying commands is using the `--target` flag.

Comment: @toskv How do I see the outputted .js files? I can't find them in my project.

Comment: you can just take that class and paste it in the typescript playground, there's no need to scour your project files. Although learning where to find them wouldn't hurt you either. :)  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: @toskv Tried pasting it and looking at the js. I'm having trouble seeing why it's not working. Would you care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Change   `public combinedVSData(): Array<GraphData>{}` instead of   `public get combinedVSData():` Array{

Comment: @echonax, the OP is calling  patient.combinedVSData, he doesn't need getter. He has also Java background which may confuse him. And I guess the OP upvoted.

Comment: "Needing" a getter is one thing, wrong usage is another. OP is using the getter in a correct way. The problem is related with something else. And why do you think getters/setters are a worse solution? Angular source code uses them too.

Comment: @Vega misled to what?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining combinedVSData as a getter instead as a method.
I did an example to show you the difference between a getter and a method

```
class Patient {
    constructor(public id: number) {
    }

    // getter
    public get getId(): number {
        return this.id;
    }

    // method
    public getIdMethod(): number {
        return this.id;
    }
}

const patient: Patient = new Patient(1);

console.log(patient.id);            // 1
console.log(patient.getId);         // 1
console.log(patient.getIdMethod);   // function () { return this.id; }
console.log(patient.getIdMethod()); // 1
```

console.log(patient);

[image]

Comment: OP is already using it with correct syntax like `movedPatient.getCombinedVSData`

Comment: @echonax no they're not. They should be using `movedPatient.combinedVSData`

Comment: @Duncan ah my eyes deceived me. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it was `getCombinedVSData()` because I had tried to make it a normal function. I simply forgot to change it back before posting here. The result is the same.

Comment: maybe worth it to do console.log(movedPatient) and see what is the object obtained by JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData("patient"));

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora I did and it looks fine, although I can't see the getter method in the object, but I don't think I'm supposed to?

Comment: I just edited my answer, you should see the method under __proto__ and the getter under the object itself

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora The getter is not on my object. Do you have any clue why?

Comment: I think because JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData("patient") is returning an object, not a class... you should do new Patient(.....) somewhere...  I think